# connecting to multiple data bases from single application using servlet and jsp's

Tags: mysql, oracle, jsp, servlets

can any one help me regarding this ,can i  connect to oracle and mysql databases from single  application ?. My application actually validates users according to their email which are stored in mysql and simultaneously some other data is displayed once the user i loged in. what changed are needed to achieve this task. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Create two datasource instances and configure each to communicate with the different databases. Only create one instance of each datasource (via the 'static' word below) for the entire project and keep them alive for the duration that the application is running. Get database connections from them as needed. The datasource should provide pooled connections. Here is some pseudo code:

```
private static DataSource dataSource1;
private static DataSource dataSource2;

//in a constructor:

        OracleDataSource db1 = new OracleDataSource();
        db1.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:xxxx:xxx");
        db1.setUser("xxx");
        db1.setPassword("xxxxx");
        db1.setDriverType("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSource1 = db1;


        OracleDataSource db2 = new OracleDataSource();
        db2.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@yyyy:yyyy:yy");
        db2.setUser("yy");
        db2.setPassword("yy");
        db2.setDriverType("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        dataSource2 = db2;
```